# Any program that locks programs for certain times?

Tags: software-recommendation, productivity, time-management

I'm instituting some New Year's resolutions around productivity.

One of those is to limit the frequency at which I check my email  — and other communications channels.

I primarily use [Rambox](http://www.rambox.pro) for this purpose.

I am looking for a productivity app which limits access to programs to either:

a) Certain times of the day 
b) A cumulative period per day (e.g., one hour in a 24 hour period).

I've checked out some of the parental control tools but clearly these are intended for a slightly different use-case.

Does any program exist of this nature or is developing one — or developing self-control — my best bet?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anything you could implement...you could also circumvent or defeat.

Comment: Perhaps something like software rental program and rent it to yourself at one hour per day. You want warning five minutes before so you don't loose email you were writing.